# Como Puedo Contar los Elementos de una Lista Agrupada

Tags: python

Teniendo una lista agrupada:

```
despachoAsignado = [(1, [54, 35, 50, 0, 33, 35, 42, 33, 36]), (2, [0, 48, 48]), (3, [35, 52, 55, 34, 54, 39]), (4, [0, 0, 0, 54, 36, 40, 50]), (5, [0, 44, 35, 37, 32])]
```

necesito contar los elementos de la sublista i[1], generando otra lista como la siguiente:

```
totalDespachoAsignado = [(1, 9), (2, 3), (3, 6), (4, 7), (5, 5)]
```

intente generarla de la siguiente manera:

```
totalDespachoAsignado=0
    for i in despachoAgrupado:
        if(type(i) is list):
            totalDespachoAsignado += contar(i)
        else:
            totalDespachoAsignado += 1
print(contar)
```

¿Como podría sacar esta nueva lista con el conteo de los datos n de la sublista?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si la estructura de `despachoAsignado` es consistente en todos los casos, lo más simple es usar una "comprensión de listas" para reelaborarla según lo que buscas:

```
totalDespachoAsignado = [(e[0], len(e[1])) for e in despachoAsignado]
print(totalDespachoAsignado)

[(1, 9), (2, 3), (3, 6), (4, 7), (5, 5)]
```

- básicamente recorremos cada elemento `for e in despachoAsignad`
- y lo reescribimos como una tupla `(e[0], len(e[1]))`

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, impecable solución.